# How to remove parameters from url?

Tags: parameters

I've tried something like this

```
    PageReference pr = ApexPages.currentPage();
    pr.getParameters().remove('id');
```

but that doesn't seem to have worked as the `id` returns on the next page.

Comment: Did you mean to write `ApexPages.currentPage();ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();` or is that a typo?

Comment: Are you going to redirect to a new page?

Comment: @CasparHarmer no, good catch.

Comment: @crop1645 yes, eventually on this page.

Answer (score 2):

```
PageReference currPr = ApexPages.currentPage();
PageReference newPr = new PageReference('/apex/myPage');
for (String parm : currPr.getParameters().keySet())
     if (parm.equalsIgnoreCase('id') {}
     else newPr.getParameters().put(parm,currPr.getParameters().get(parm));

newPr.setRedirect(true);
return newPr;
```

There is a [good blog post by Dave Helgerson](http://www.davehelgerson.com/?p=334) that covers various permutations